# How to move an image in Lua?

Tags: image, lua

I am new to Lua programming and I am having problems while trying to move an image from a set of coordinates to another.

What I am trying to create is to be used with the X-Plane flight simulator. There is a library called SASL (www.1-sim.com), that was created to make plugins (for X-Plane) creation easir, since the default language is C++ and many people find it difficult.

In general, SASL works as a bridge between Lua and X-Plane, in general lines, the scripts you write reads some data straight from X-Plane (DataRefs) while it is running and depending on the code you wrote its execute commands or many other things that it is possible.

So, when using SASL to create cockpit/panel gauges it uses a base file, named 'avionics.lua' that works as a class and loads all gauges you create for the specific aircraft you are working on. For example my avionics.lua file looks like this:

```
size = { 2048, 2048 }

components = {
flaps {};
};
```

where, 'size' is the size that will be used for things to be drawn and components is an array of gauges, in this case the flaps gauge.

The rest of the work is to create the gauge functionality and this is done in a separate file, in my case, called 'flaps.lua'.

Within flaps.lua, is where I need to code the flaps indicator functionality which is to load 2 images: one for the back ground and the second one for the flaps indicator.

The first image is a fixed image. The second one will move throught the 'y' axis based on the flaps indicator DataRef (flapsDegree property below).

The code below when X-Plane is running displays the background image and the flaps indicator on its first stage which is 0 as you can see on the image.

```
size = {78,100}

local flapsDegree = globalPropertyf("sim/cockpit2/controls/flap_ratio")
local background = loadImage("gfx/Flaps.png")
local indicator = loadImage("gfx/Flaps_Indicator.png")
local flaps = get(flapsPosition)

components = {
texture { position = {945, 1011, 60, 100}, image = background},
texture { position = {959, 1097, 30, 9},   image = indicator},
}
```

Image [image]

Now, the problem comes when I need to implement the logic for moving the 'indicator' image through the 'y' axis.

I have tried this code without success:

```
if flaps == 0.333 then
indicator.position = {959, 1075, 30, 9}
end
```

So how could I accomplish that?

Comment: I can only assume that you are talking about this library  https://github.com/der-On/sasl as native Lua does not provide any of those functions. Please add more information. I should not have to google what code you are talking about...

Comment: Yes that is correct. Tell me what information you need so that I can provide to you.

Comment: well tell us more about your project, which libraries you use, maybe some screenshots of what you want and what you get instead and so on... so far I have the impression that you did not even read the documentation of that library as it describes how to draw stuff at certain coordinates.
I'm sure you also have more than those 8 lines of code you can share with us.

Comment: That documentation from the github is extremely outdate, the current SASL is here: www.1-sim.com. As for reading the documentation, I have read, problem is the documentation has just a description of each function and no usage example which complicates to me. As for the code, all the code from the flaps.lua file is already on the post. If you wish we can open a chat here or skype which I think it would be better.

Comment: I don't know that library. so will 99.999% of all users here. so if you want help you better edit your question in a way that assumes that the guy you are asking has no idea of what you are talking about. just a good understanding of the programming language and experience in reading documentations and using other libraries. everything else that would be important like what files you have, how they work together should come from you.

Comment: Ok I will edit the question and try to make it clearer.

Comment: I have edited the question, maybe now is better explained.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the SALS library. I just had a quick look into it.

Everything you need to know is in the manuals on the website you linked.
In particular http://www.1-sim.com/files/SASL300.pdf

Everytime your screen is updated each components draw() function will be called.

So if you want to change something dynamically you have to put that into the component's draw function.

If you open the SALS sources you'll find basic components which show you how to use that stuff. One of them is needle.lua:

```
-- default angle
defineProperty("angle", 0)

-- no image
defineProperty("image")


function draw(self)
    local w, h = getTextureSize(get(image))

    local max = w
    if h > max then
        max = h
    end

    local rw = (w / max) * 100
    local rh = (h / max) * 100
    drawRotatedTexture(get(image), get(angle), 
        (100 - rw) / 2, (100 - rh) / 2, rw, rh)
end
```

If you check the manual you'll find that there is not only a drawRotatedTexture function but many other functions for drawing stuff. Just play around. Try drawTexture for your purpose.

If you don't know what you have to program, open every single lua file in the library and read it together with the Lua reference manual and the SALS documentation until you understand what is going on. Once you understand the existing code you can extend it with ease.